# Constructing a generic class

Tags: java, generics

I have a simple question regarding java generics. How do I construct a generic class?
I have this class :

```
public class SearchResult<T extends Model> {

    public List<T> results ;

    public Integer count ;

    public SearchResult(List<T> results, Integer count){
        this.results = results;
        this.count = count ;
    }
}
```

Now i would like to create a new instance is SearchResult but then when i do this i get an error . `SearchResult result = new SearchResult<MyModel>(myListOfMyModels, mycount);`

Comment: what is the error message? And where do you declare `<T>`?

Comment: A lot of people edited out the original problems in the question...thusly changing the context of the question.

Comment: If you look at the history, you'll notice the original problems in the question were masked by erroneous formatting. Stack Overflow was dropping the < and > making it look like there were no type parameters on SearchResult when joshua had not entered the question that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your class definition should look like

```
public class SearchResult<T> {

    public List<T> results ;

    public Integer count ;

    public SearchResult(List<T> results, Integer count){
        this.results = results;
        this.count = count ;
    }
}
```

Then:

```
SearchResult result = new SearchResult<String>(myListOfStrings, mycount);
```

I'm assuming that since `myListOfStrings` appears to be a string, you need to define `T` as a `String`

Answer (score 2):

Now that I fixed your formatting, it's clear what's happening. You declared the generic parameter to be something that extends `Model`, yet you're trying to instantiate the class with a `String` parameter value. I'm sure that `String` does not extend `Model` (whatever that is).

Comment: Hi Ted, I have corrected edited. Actually am constructing with a List of my custom class that extends Model.

Answer (score 0):

The type of T needs to be scoped to something like a class or a method.

In this instance you probably want to add the type parameter T to the search result class, giving something like:

```
public class SearchResult<T> {
    // as before
}
```

And change the instantiation to something like:

```
SearchResult<String> result = new SearchResult<String>(myListOfStrings, mycount);
```

Edit: Initially SearchResult had no type parameter so I suggested adding one. If the issue is that T must extend Model, then you won't be able to create a SearchResult<String>, as String doesn't extend Model.